# I can not change password length complicity by editing common-password

Tags: password

I can not change password length complicity by editing common-password

if edit common-password file, i can change all things except password length,
the password can be possible to make length up to two characters hence i would wish to get eight digit password.
i really would like to know its possible or not

Answer (score 0):

You can use cracklib pam module to set minimum length to password and much more.
Install using:

```
apt-get install libpam-cracklib
```

Add the line below to the common-password:

```
password        requisite                       pam_cracklib.so retry=3 minlen=8 difok=3
```

before the line:

```
password        [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so obscure use_authtok try_first_pass sha512
```

[More info](http://www.deer-run.com/~hal/sysadmin/pam_cracklib.html)

Comment: This Solution i have already tried but did not help me